# Instagram like filters using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been looking for a way to develop Instagram like filters using React-Native. I have created filters using another mobile framework called Ionic which uses the webview to create apps, but the filters are much too slow. How could I manipulate images to create such filtered effects using react-native.

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You can check my [react-native-image-filter-kit](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit) module. It contains an Instagram like [set of filters](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit/blob/master/docs/cssgram_filters.md) ported from CSSGram project.

Usage example:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import { ToasterCompat } from 'react-native-image-filter-kit'

const imageStyle = { width: 320, height: 320 }

const atx = (
  <Image
    style={imageStyle}
    source={{ uri: 'https://una.im/CSSgram/img/atx.jpg' }}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
  />
)

const toasted = <ToasterCompat image={atx} />
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the recipes that used to implement instagram styles filter in React Native using gl-react in the [medium story](https://medium.com/@wcandillon/instagram-filter-63e169a54ce3).

Comment: will those also support the init based projects or are they only for expo. #your_u_tube_fan

Comment: For plain React Native projects without expo, you can just switch gl-react-expo for https://github.com/gre/gl-react/tree/master/packages/gl-react-native.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd need to look at implementing an OpenGl view to get good performance. If you're doing it on the device then the filters should probably be done using GLSL shaders. I was hoping to find a polyfill-type component for WebGL, but haven't found one yet.

The [react-canvas](https://github.com/mjohnston/react-canvas) project is quite interesting (even though it's about canvas, not webGL) - and might be worth exploring.

EDIT: it's a long time after, but there is [gl-react](https://github.com/ProjectSeptemberInc/gl-react) for exactly the purpose of doing advanced effects like Instagram filters over images.

Comment: We can use gl-react but there is no way to get the effected image with gl-react.

Comment: Yes, there is @SukhdeepSinghKalra You can get it with Surface.captureFrame()